# Disk based STL replacement for c++

Tags: c++, memory, stl

I've recently build an application that relies heavily on stl queues, and have run into memory issues, the queue grows to big to fit in the machines memory. Are there any disk-backed opensource, IO / memory efficient queue implementations that can be plugged inplace of a stl queue making my app magically use less RAM?

I would like something with read/write buffer-mechanisms - since my application does arround 50k enqueues/dequeues pr sec, and the objects are rather small.

My queue contains pairs of 32 bit integers, making every entry takeup 64 bit, linked lists are there for out of the question since they will double the memory consumption.

Comment: The underlying container for a queue is a deque, if you changed it to a list it would fit better into memory (at the cost of performance) though deque is pretty memory efficient

Comment: [The STXXL looks promising](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @aaronman, to be honest I already implemented a cyclical arraybased queue squezing the data, what I would like is orders of magnitude, taking up gigs on disk

Comment: Array based queue is bad because then you are forcing the memory to be contiguous

Comment: @juanchopanza Thats what I thought, it does however seem a little unmaintained - no c++11 support in there.. I might have to add it my self

Comment: @aaronman: an `std::list` is less subjected to memory fragmentation, but it has overhead for each element (both due to the next/prev pointers and to the need for a heap allocation per each element), I don't think it could help in any way (actually, IMO it would make things way worse). Also, `deque` is not `vector`, it doesn't need contiguous storage for all the elements (typically it works with medium-sized element chunks).

Comment: @MatteoItalia he claims he made an array based implementation, asking for contiguous memory that large seems unlikely to perform well at all. Personally I would have thought std::deque would work well because it has the best of both worlds but I just wanted to explain that there are other options. The STXXL doesn't seem like a bad idea, but what's the point of giving it as advice if you haven't used it either

Comment: @aaronman: he's probably using `std::deque`, since he says is using "plain STL queues" and, as you said, the default underlying container is deque; still, my point is simply that the `std::list` is probably a really bad choice, especially since he is storing small elements. As for the STXXL, I didn't suggest it, so I don't get exactly why your last point seems to be addressed at me...

Comment: @MatteoItalia I just wanted to give the opinion of a person who wants to solve the problem without resorting to including a big library in the project, also he didn't originally state that his data type was so small when I answered the question hence why I originally recommended the list, if the datatype is very large it can offer better performance

Comment: Why not let the OS's virtual memory system handle it?  As long as you are on a 64-bit OS you shouldn't be able to come close to exhausting your address space, assuming that your swap file is sufficiently large.

Comment: @Graznarak thats a horible sollution, now the OS will have to swap anything older out of RAM before my data goes out, and when ever I access it, I will have to wait for a pagefault to get it back again.

Comment: @MartinKristiansen The data still has to get to L1 cache to be used.  That means pages faulted and lines invalidated.  The biggest difference is that you are managing it rather than letting the OS manage it.

Comment: @Graznarak you are of caurse right, and I bet I am alot better at mannaging it than then OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would look into using [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/). It re-implements many of the stl container interfaces with a filesystem backend. One of those implementations is for the deque structure.

Comment: the biggest problem with stxxl is the fact that it does not seem maintained.. the code will not compile with c++11

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't compile in C++11? From the docs 'Support for C++0x and C++11 is integrated and automatically detected. No core parts of STXXL require C++11.'

Comment: it might just be the tests.

Comment: In file included from ../include/stxxl/bits/common/utils.h:29:
../include/stxxl/bits/compat/type_traits.h:19:10: fatal error: 'tr1/type_traits' file not found
#include <tr1/type_traits>

Comment: It appears the developers have been actively updating the particular file your referencing -- it seems you're compiler is not setting `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` (I think you're using gcc?). You could pull request that file to ammend the line to be `#if defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X) || __cplusplus >= 201103L` which should clear up that problem. Beyond that compiler specific issues may exist with any library (but that's a little beyond this question's scope).

Comment: I'm using the llvm-gcc that came with apples Maverics, Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)..

Comment: That's unfortunate as it was suggested elsewhere on the web for gcc. I'm not too familiar with clang's internals so I would search for a precomp clang C++11 indicator elsewhere on SO or the web. If I had actual experience with clang specifically I'd give a suggestion here instead, but the overall problem is that if statement's failure to detect C++11 is active in your compiler.

Comment: I tried the hack of simply defining the variable, and compiling it almost worked some minor issues still.. like the use of sleep

Answer (score 2):

Yes, please try STXXL.
But don't use the deque if you can avoid random access (i.e. operator[]).
Use stxxl::sequence instead, it is efficient in external memory.

Disclaimer: I am reviving the library. Please send me a patch if you fix the C++11 problem, which is probably due to MacOSX's toolchain.

Comment: It looks like its an instance of the macro check that checks for c++11 not recornizing the gcc that comes with Maverics..

Answer (score 0):

`std::queue` is a container adaptor, meaning it is essentially an interface over another container. In this case the default is `std::deque` which is represented in memory as a vector of constant size arrays, since the vector contains pointers to the arrays it fits pretty well in memory. If you need things to be even less contiguous you could try making the backend an `std::list`, linked structures can often handle very large amounts of data better since they don't have to be contiguous.

You could also give your own backend to the interface, it has to meet the requirements of [SequenceContainer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer)